# How to print multiple files in awk?

Tags: awk, glob

What is wrong with this file please? I owuld like to print all lines from file01, file02, file03 ... file11.

```
awk '{print}' file[01-11].txt > file
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are running this in BASH, the `[01-11]` second is not in the correct format. Instead, consider the following:

```
awk '{print}' file{01..11}.txt > file
```

This is again, assuming a specific shell. If you are running this `awk` command in a shell that does not support the `{##..##}` nomenclature, consider testing how your `file[01-11].txt` is expanding first -- I imagine it's not expanding out to the files you think.

Comment: Thank you very much. And please when there are three columns in file and I would like > file.csv, how to set that to be in three columns and not in only one?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `cat` itself for it like(since you are only printing and not doing any other operation):

```
cat Input_file{01..11}.txt > file
```

In case you really want to do only in `awk` then try:

```
awk '1' Input_file{01..11}.txt > file
```

Comment: @Archie, Could you please check this answer once and let me know if this helped you?

Comment: Thank you very much and how to do the outbut > file.csv to have three columns? I tried to use deliminer, but it does not help.

Comment: @Archie, Did you use something like `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$3}' Input_file{01..11}.txt > file` This should be the command.